# Why isn't my code passing the W3 validator?

Tags: html, css, validation

I have to use codepen to write up a website and then get my code to pass the W3 validator. The problem is that, whichever way I try to check the code, it comes up with different error messages.

When I copy and paste the whole code into W3, it says that I need <DOCTYPE!> and the other things like that (that I'm not allowed to type into codepen, without getting an error message on that end).

However, when I go into debug mode and put the URL directly into W3, it comes up with a load of errors that don't exist- the code it specifies isn't anywhere in my code.

Has anyone else had issues getting codepen validated by w3?

edit: codepen is https://codepen.io/johng003/pen/rNjrrOb

```css
:root{
  font-family:"Montserrat", serif;}

body{
  background-image:url("https://i.imgur.com/kfFhV7c.png");
}

#nav-bar{
  position:fixed;
  width:100%;
  top:0px;
  left:0px;
  background-color: rgb(235, 52, 128);
  padding:13px;
  font-family:"Playfair Display", serif;
  font-size: 18px;
  z-index:98;
}

.nav-link{ 
  margin: 0px 40px 10px 40px;}

.nav-link:link {
  color: yellow;
  background-color: transparent;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.nav-link:visited {
  color: white;
  background-color: transparent;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.nav-link:hover {
  color: #F8B8E4;
  background-color: transparent;
  text-decoration: underline;
}

.header-img {
  position:fixed;
  left: 91%;
  top:0%;
  max-width: 9%;
  min-width:7%;
  height: auto;
  z-index: 99;
}

h1{
  position:relative;
  left:40vw;
  top: 25px;
  font-size:40px;
  color:rgb(235, 52, 128);
}

.offers:link {
  color: rgb(235, 52, 128);
  background-color: transparent;
  text-decoration: underline;
}

.offers:visited {
  color: purple;
  background-color: transparent;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.offers:hover {
  color: purple;
  background-color: transparent;
  text-decoration: underline;
}

.donut-ignore{
  font-size: 20px;
  position:absolute;
  top:75px;
  left: 39vw;
}

h2{
  color:rgb(235, 52, 128);
  font-size: 25px;
}
.gallery-heading{
  position:relative;
  top: 15px;
}
.videointro{
  font-size: 18px;
}

iframe{
    border-width: 0px;
}

.donut-gallery{
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:row;
  justify-content:space-around;
  align-items:center;
  flex-wrap:wrap;
}

#donut1, #donut2, #donut3, #donut4, #donut5, #donut6{
  max-width:40vw;
  clip-path:circle(45%)
}

#donut3{
  max-height:300px;
}

#donut2{
  max-height:465px;
}

@media (min-width: 400px){
      #donut1, #donut2, #donut3, #donut4, #donut5, #donut6{
        max-width:400px;
  }

.flavours{
    font-size:18px;
  } 
.largertext{
    font-size: 18px;
  }
  
.flavourlist{
    font-size: 18px;
    position:relative;
    padding: 0px 0px 20px 0px;
    
  }
  
.orderonline{
    position: relative;
    top:10px;
  }
  
 .instoreheader{position:relative;
  top: 10px;}
```

```html
<body>
  <header id="header">
    <nav id="nav-bar">
      <a href="#donut-gallery" class="nav-link">Donut Gallery</a>
      <a href="#order-online" class="nav-link">Order Online</a>
      <a href="#order-instore" class="nav-link">Order In Store</a>
    </nav>
    <img src="https://i.imgur.com/NK8Zbmn.png" alt="The store's logo; a black and white drawing of a donut" class="header-img">
  </header>
  <main>
    <h1><em> Divine Donuts </em></h1>
    <p class="donut-ignore"> Donut Ignore Our Fabulous <a target="_blank" href="https://www.donutdigest.com/blog/" class="offers"> Offers! </a> </p>
    <article>
      <h2 class="gallery-heading"> Donut Gallery </h2>
      <p class="videointro"> This is how our divine donuts are made...</p>
      <iframe id="video" width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/DePRyZE5sn4" title="YouTube video player" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
      <br>
      <div class="donut-gallery">
        <img id="donut1" src="https://i.imgur.com/yueQzkr.jpg" alt="A dozen donuts with sprinkles" class="donutimage1">
        <img id="donut2" src="https://i.imgur.com/QfhD5o4.jpg" alt="A tower of colourful donuts" class="donutimage2">
        <img id="donut3" src="https://i.imgur.com/oXPlX3S.jpg" alt="A donut with galaxy mirror glaze" class="donutimage3">
        <img id="donut4" src="https://i.imgur.com/guK5rGP.jpg" alt="Halloween themed dounuts" class="donutimage4">
        <img id="donut5" src="https://i.imgur.com/ER3hBG4.jpg" alt="An oversized pink sprinkles donut" class="donutimage5">
        <img id="donut6" src="https://i.imgur.com/HOzPDAg.jpg" alt="A donut with cookies and cream filling" class="donutimage6">
      </div>
    </article>
    <section id="buyers">
      <div class="flavours">
        <p> <strong> Decide on next month's special flavour now:</strong> </p>
        <form action="https://www.freecodecamp.com/email-submit">
          <fieldset>
            <legend> Choose the next flavour of the month</legend>
            <label for="Banana-and-peanut-butter"> Banana and Peanut butter</label>
            <input id="Banana-and-peanut-butter" value="Banana" type="radio" name="donut-type">
            <button accesskey="b"> or press b </button>
            <label for="Marshmallow-and-salted-caramel">Marshmallow-and-salted-caramel</label>
            <input id="Marshmallow-and-salted-caramel" value="Marshmallow" type="radio" name="donut-type">
            <button accesskey="m"> or press m </button>
            <label for="Blueberry-and-apple">Blueberry-and-apple</label>
            <input id="Blueberry-and-apple" value="blueberry" type="radio" name="donut-type">
            <button accesskey="a"> or press a </button>
            <button type="submit">Submit</button>
          </fieldset>
        </form>
        <br>
        <p class="largertext"> Our past flavours of the month were...</p>
        <ul>
          <li class="flavourlist"> April: Rainbow Surprise </li>
          <li class="flavourlist"> March: Bubblegum and popping candy </li>
          <li class="flavourlist"> February: Biscoff and Oreos </li>
        </ul>
      </div>

      <div id="order-online">
        <h2 class="orderonline"> Order bespoke creations online </h2>
        <p class="largertext"> To make large or bespoke orders, please fill out the form below and one of our donut devotees will be in touch before the end of the day... </p>
        <form id="form" action="https://www.freecodecamp.com/email-submit">
          <input type="text" placeholder="Name" required>
          <input type="number" placeholder="Phone number" required>
          <input id="email" name="email" type="email" placeholder="Email" required>

          <input id="submit" type="submit" value="submit">
        </form>
      </div>
      <br>
      <div id="order-instore">
        <h2 class="instoreheader"> Order in-Store </h2>
        <p class="largertext"> To order in store, simply pop to our Antartica branch.

          Opening times are 10AM-6PM 7 days a week. </p>

        <img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,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" alt="A map showing the location of our antartica branch">
      </div>
    </section>
  </main>
  <script src="https://cdn.freecodecamp.org/testable-projects-fcc/v1/bundle.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: Then please add your code. Also W3C exactly tells you why your code is not passing. PS: it's `<!DOCTYPE html>` and every HTML document has to start with it. With HTML5 it is even more simple as in HTML4 you would have to add much more to it.

Comment: You do really need `<!DOCTYPE html>` to declare the version of html you're using https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_doctype.asp

Comment: I know that, but if you put it into codepen, you get an error message saying to take it out (as it automatically includes it). You can only put the contents of <body>

Comment: @tacoshy as I said in the title, I'm new to coding. I don't understand what the W3 is trying to tell me, that's why I'm asking you guys. I'm trying to get onto a coding course, so know practically nothing atm, it has taken me hours and hours to just figure out how to get this shitty website together

Comment: yes I read that. I highly advice not to use Codepen to write a website. Its a terrible way in learning. Its not intended to write a website but as a way to share code snippets or programm projects. If you want to write a website use an actual IDE such as `Visual Studio Code`. They have a better syntax highlighting aswell as informations about syntaxes. they also mark most errors directly.

Comment: That combination of requirements makes no sense at all. Who in their sane mind would give you such a task?

Comment: @connexo wrong question? I think you wanted to comment the homework question.

Comment: ok thanks guys- I have come to the conclusion that, I'm not going crazy, it really is just impossible to write up something that passes both codepen and the w3 validator's requirements. I've contacted my course and should be able to speak to somebody on Sunday. I'm about ready to throw my computer out the window now so I'm logging off for a bit! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Error #2: Start tag seen without seeing a doctype first. Expected `<!DOCTYPE html>`.**

You missing the `<!DOCTYPE html>` tag. it is not optional. It is required to tell the browser which version of HTML is used.

**Error #1: Consider adding a lang attribute to the html start tag to declare the language of this document.**

This mean that you should add as 2nd line a tag declaring the language of your website. This is helpful for search engines and screen-readers. As example: `<html lang="en">`

**Error #3: Element head is missing a required instance of child element title.**

Your `<head></head>` section is missing. Also part of the head-section is the `<title>` tag. There you are required to add a title that is also shown then inside the browser tab at the top.

Also part of the head content are meta data such as search tags. Also your links for external CSS, Scripts or libraries.

---

Last but not least, codepen is only a webbased site to see the result of soemthing or to share code snippets. Its not for fully programming a website. Its simliar to an IDE. If you want a fully working website then you should use an actual IDE such as `Visual Studio Code` as example.

Comment: I have to use codepen because that is what the course has told us to use. We're not allowed to use anything else. I can't add any of that information because it brings up an error message in codepen. You can only put what's in the <body> there, if you put <!DOCTYPE>, you duplicate it because codepen already does that behind the scenes, and then it causes all sorts of janky problems. Believe me, I wouldn't use codepen if I had a choice. I feel like I've been set up with an impossible task